# i am try to install laravel 6 pdf package "composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf"

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

[image]

I'm trying composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf. But i got:

```
E:\wamp64\www\laravel\Bugler>composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://repo.packagist.org/p/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf%24121356f3b13be1ea852a1b1d7ee643fe8af75206dd35d9e62998d63
  5a75f929c.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
  failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--fixed] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] [<packages>]...
```

can any one help me?
I also try to resolve this.

`php artisan cache:clear`

`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue is already listed on `Composer github repository`

This issue occurs due to incorrect proxy configuration. Check your proxy configuration .

Also if you  are using any antivirus then disable it and try again

https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/6891

Answer (score 0):

Delete your `composer.lock` file in your project directory and run below command:

```
composer install
```

Or you can try to run below command:

```
composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf:0.8.2
```

Comment: when i try E:\wamp64\www\laravel\Bugler>composer install
You are running Composer with SSL/TLS protection disabled.
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local...
Updating symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.13.1 => v1.14.0): Downloading (failed)